# Get current username in view MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm trying to get the current username logged in in a view but i can't do it.
I have this code:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(User.Identity.Name))
    </div>
```

But it doesn't work. I want to when the user goes to the form it displays his username automatically in a way he can't edit. Everytime i try something i search or it doesn't appear the username or it sends a blank space instead of the username.
Can someone help me? Or should i declare in the class or controller that the variable Name is the current username (if so how can i do it?)?
I'm using MVC 4 with EF 4.5 and SimpleMembership

Comment: You should assign the user name to a model property in the controller, and then pass it to the view for display

Comment: It depends on how you using `SimpleMembership` What returns `User.Identity.GetUserId()` in your case?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1883089.aspx?SimpleMembership+simple+question+how+to+retrieve+currentUser+

Comment: @teovankot when i insert User.Identity.GetUserId() in the way i'm making the view it doesn't appear nothing. But in other cases return the id of the current user

Comment: if you do user.identity.name without textbox does it display?

Comment: @coder771 yes but when i click create (this is a view to create) it creates like a blank parameter

Comment: have a breakpoint on view and check if you get value in it

Comment: @coder771 it doesn't get any value, it gets NULL

Comment: check if User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like following.

```
@Html.TextBox("Name", User.Identity.Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for us in an Umbraco Razor view. I think it will be the same in plain MVC outside Umbraco

```
You are logged in as @Context.User.Identity.Name)
```